# Two problems with one block of code (Random is the same and ifs are not doing anything when condition is met)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Contains a bit of discord.js code, but it's explained**

What I'm trying to do is make it so when a user uses a specific command, it starts a random variable, which is used to add a random enemy. When I use the command though, it gives me the same number (Which used to be 4, but after changing my code a little bit, it is now 1), and doesn't do what that number is supposed to do (The if statement does not start)

My code that I think is having the problem:

```
        var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        if(e = 1){
            userData.skeletons + 1;
        }
        else if(e = 2){
            userData.skeletons + 1;
        }
        else if (e = 3){
            userData.minotaurs + 1;
        }              
        else if(e = 4){
            userData.skeletons + 1;
        }
        console.log(e)
```

The complete code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "search")) { //if the message the 
//user sends is equal to my prefix (bp!) plus the word search, it runs the 
//below code
    if(userData.stamina >= 3){
        userData.stamina - 3
        var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        if(e = 1){
            userData.skeletons + 1;
        }
        else if(e = 2){
            userData.skeletons + 1;
        }
        else if (e = 3){
            userData.minotaurs + 1;
        }              
        else if(e = 4){
            userData.skeletons + 1;
        }
        console.log(e)
        message.reply('To see if ya found anything, use bp!enemies')
        //replies to the user who used the command with the above message
    }
    else{ //this else is for if they do not have enough stamina
        message.reply('You require at least 3 stamina to do this!')
        console.log(`${message.author.id} You require at least 3 stamina to 
        do this!`)            
    }
}
```

I've created comments for those who need a bit more understanding of the code and the discord.js code.

I've checked my userData variables (variables that are unique to each user), and they're all right.
I've looked through other questions, but it didn't look like they had a solution
Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Your are not changing anything as a result of your conditions, just computing a new value and then throwing it away.

Comment: What do you expect `Math.random()` to return and why?

Comment: You must replace your '=' in the 'if' by '==' to do a correct check. Also you could replace the 'var' by 'let'. Google for difference between 'var / let'  , '= / =='

Comment: Thank you galigator! You fixed my random is always 1 problem!
Unfortunately my other problem is still there, thank you for helping though :)

Comment: PM 77-1 I expect my `Math.random()` to return a random number between 1 and 4, so that it can add an userData variable according to what number was gotten in `Math.random()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many problems with this code.
`if(e = 1)`  should be `if(e == 1)` and `userData.stamina - 3` should be `userData.stamina -= 3`.

`userData.skeletons + 1` should be `userData.skeletons++`

Comment: I figured this out a while ago, but this is the solution, thank you. :)